# Как добавить путь, содержащий двоеточие в переменную PATH на ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

Мой Golang лежит: /windows/d:/Programm/Go/bin
Как его добавить в PATH, ведь на Linux двоеточие служит разделителем путей?

Answer (score 2):

Краткий ответ - нельзя добавить каталог с двоеточием в PATH.

> Since  is a separator in this context, directory names that might be used in PATH should not include a  character.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641294/if-there-is-a-colon-in-the-directory-name-how-could-i-add-it-to-path
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311339/why-was-colon-chosen-as-path-separator

Но что делать, если очень хочется?

Первый способ - просто смонтировать диск винды по удобному. Открываете /etc/fstab и добавляете как нужно. Один и тот же диск можно смонтировать в десяток мест.

Второй способ - создать симлинку на нужный каталог прям в домашний каталог.

```
ln -s  /windows/d:/Programm/Go/bin ~/go
```

и теперь в PATH добавлять только с домашнего каталога.

Но как правильно заметили в комментариях, не факт, что это все нормально взлетит. Поэтому, я для начала сделал бы бекап.

И третий, правильный способ - сорцы залить на систему контроля версий:)